# Can someone update my post?

Tags: discussion, support

My post has been on hold for some days now. No one (except some guy which today said if something would work, it didn't) is even viewing the post.

After I saw my post was on hold, I made it more clear, as the reason it was on hold was because it was unclear what I was asking. And, no one still saw the question. Here's the post:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343053/how-do-you-replicate-windows-1-01-graphics*

Can someone please update my post and remove the "on hold"? I want some answers.

Comment: 'I want real Windows 1.01 or better graphics, or similar.' - April fool?

Comment: Maybe you can find an old version and run it in a VM:)

Comment: No. And i'm not planning only batch, well, you can also suggest me C or C++. I tried dislin, but there was no GCC, and i couldn't download it. But it had some neat applications. And a old version of what?

Comment: Just edited so it becomes even better.

Comment: To me at least, the question is still unclear. You say you want to emulate it in the command prompt, which leads me to believe you just want the text displayed.. which is simply black and white. Unless you want *graphics* and the calculator inside a *command prompt* which is bordering on the impossible. Assuming a C++ solution is acceptable, that brings it way into the 'too broad' territory.. you'd be best off reading a C++ GUI tutorial.

Comment: I want it on the command line OR SIMILAR (didn't include but whatever), and a C, C++ or Batch solution is available.

Comment: There are ancient frameworks for building text-mode "graphical" applications - in the Turbo Pascal camp, it was called [TurboVision.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision) I'm sure there are C/C++ equivalents, too. The nice graphics were achieved by rewriting the ASCII character table to allow for nice-looking GUI elements (which was possible, and awesome). Not sure why anyone would want to go through all this in 2016, though. It was very painful to work with.

Comment: @Rob Just edited it.

Comment: Oh, TurboVision exists for GCC as well http://tvision.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Pekka웃 oh great.  I can hardly wait to install it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Very informative. I may use that.

Comment: @MartinJames make sure you use the latest [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/)

Comment: @StarOS I can't find any resources about rewriting the character table... I used to do that to build nice-looking GUIs in text mode. Maybe the practice has a name that I can't remember.

Comment: Oh great, i make 2 good questions and both get 2 or more dislikes. Stackoverflow, do you really want me to quit for a year again?

Comment: @StarOS You have been given reasons *why* people think it's not a good question. It's nearly impossible for someone to figure out what you want, and even if they did, your question is really asking for someone to build an entire application for you. There is no specific question there. You are getting downvoted on meta because people disagree with your request to reopen the question.

Answer (score 12):

Your question is in terrible quality as of now. Reading your newly updated post, you seem to not read the Help Center or the Tour at all because this is your question plus some other text:

> How can i replicate these type of graphics (or better) on a modern Command Prompt (Or similar.)?
>
> I haven't tried any code, but the closest and stable code is this (still just text, not 1.01 graphics):

The question is simply way too broad. There are probably lots and lots of ways to answer that question, thus making the question unclear of *precisely* what is asked. This means more trouble for your post and your reputation (and maybe your privilege to ask). Making a more specific question should allow the post to have a chance of reopening...

If only you tried something. The next line basically makes the post immediately ready for closure. You need to have run/tried some code in attempts to solve your problem. As you didn't, we still have no idea how to answer your question and thus the closures.

Maybe reading the articles found in the [Help Center about asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would benefit you a lot more.